# How do you write a Regex that combines a Negative Lookbehind with a Negative Lookahead to create a Negative Lookaround?

Tags: java, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, regex-look-ahead

In our Java Selenium framework, we need to write a regex that reads a string of any length and returns true if it contains the substring "bar" so long as the substring "foo" doesn't appear in the string by using a Negative Lookaround by combining a Negative Lookbehind with a Negative Lookahead.

The best regex I can construct is `(?<!foo)bar(?!.*foo).*`

It correctly matches the following desirable strings:

1. `bar`
2. `,bar,`
3. `,,bar,,`
4. `barbar`
5. `,bar,bar,`
6. `,,bar,,bar,,`
7. `barbarbar`
8. `,bar,bar,bar,`
9. `,,bar,,bar,,bar,,`

However, it also matches the following undesirable strings:

1. `,foo,bar,`
2. `,,foo,,bar,,`
3. `foobarbar`
4. `,foo,bar,bar,`
5. `,,foo,,bar,,bar,,`
6. `,bar,foo,bar,`
7. `,,bar,,foo,,bar,,`
8. `,foo,foo,bar,`
9. `,,foo,,foo,,bar,,`

My testing was conducted here: https://regex101.com/r/uhdUhU/5

Comment: You write it should match *the substring bar*, but in your list of *desriable strings*, there are matches that include commas. Can you clarify? You want to have a yes/no test on the whole input string?

Comment: Hard to do with a match, easy with a capture. See https://regex101.com/r/OzHZ1k/1

Comment: If you want separate matches in Java `(?<!foo.{0,1000})bar(?!.*foo)` See https://regex101.com/r/cIl6tC/1

Comment: Apologies I meant contains not matches - terminology was never my strong suit

Comment: @CAustin amazing, simply amazing! It's my last day before I go on holiday tomorrow and this post was a last chance saloon.

Will update the answer now!

Comment: Also `^(?:(?!bar|foo).)*bar(?:(?!bar|foo).)*$` https://regex101.com/r/JIgN9b/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@CAustin and @CarySwoveland have kindly provided the right answer: `^(?!.*foo).*bar`

`^` asserts position at start of a line

`(?!.*foo)` is the Negative Lookahead

`.` matches any character (except for line terminators)

`*` matches the previous token between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

Answer verified here: https://regex101.com/r/OzHZ1k/3

Comment: Robbie, it's not unusual to see thank you's for suggested improvements in answers, but in future consider putting them in a comment in order to keep the answer "clean". That's just my personal preference, of course, and not a biggie. Note that many members do not expect thank you's.  @CAustin, I deleted my comment above as it is no longer relevant, and will also delete this comment soon. Consider deleting your comment also.

Answer (score 2):

It would not be my preferred solution, but you could attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
 ^(?:(?!foo).)*bar(?:(?!foo).)*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdI2h8/1)

`(?:(?!foo).)` matches any one character provided that character together with the two following, if present, do not spell `"foo"`. The technique is called ["tempered greedy token solution"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).